# Convex set with empty interior lies in a proper affine subspace - infinite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Given an infinite dimensional normed vector space $X$, $S$ is a convex subset of $X$ with empty interior. **Is it true that $S$ lies in a proper affine subspace of $X$?**

There is a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590133/convex-set-with-empty-interior-lies-in-an-affine-set) but it only covers the finite dimensional case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $X=L^2(0,1)$ and $S=\{u\in X:\ u\ge 0 \ a.e.\}$. Then $S$ has no interior points, but $X=S-S$. Every $L^2$-function can be written as the difference of two non-negative $L^2$-functions.